# Difference between NSString and @ along with a string in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

What's the difference between a 'normal' `NSString` object and a string that begins with an `@`. For example `@"something"`.

Comment: The latter is not a normal `NSString`, it's an abnormal `NSString`.

Comment: A character sequence enclosed in double quotes and preceded by "@" is a NSString literal value -- anywhere (with a couple of exceptions) where one is valid so is the other.  Just as a character sequence enclosed in double quotes without the "@" is a `char[]` literal value.